# meaning of "mapped users" in learning context

Tags: meaning-in-context

On some website related to learning courses I found the phrase "mapped users".

I was in doubt what's the appropriate meaning for it in that context?
 
The meaning in google translator is "represent (an area) on a map; make a map of."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the definition of [***map***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/map) sense 3:

> 3) any maplike representation or delineation

it does not have to be "map" in the traditional sense.

Your example needs more context, by I imagine that if you make a functional diagram of a computer system, users could be *mapped* into it. The user would have a position that identifies what they can access, for example.